# Namespace deployment issue in Kubernetes Helm Chart

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I am now testing the deployment into different namespace using Kubernetes. Here I am using Kubernetes Helm Chart for that. In my chart, I have deployment.yaml and service.yaml.

When I am defining the "namespace" parameter with Helm command `helm install --upgrade`, it is not working. When I a read about that I found the statement that - "Helm 2 is not overwritten by the --namespace parameter".

I tried the following command:

```
helm upgrade --install kubedeploy --namespace=test pipeline/spacestudychart
```

**NB** Here my service is deploying with **default** namespace.

Screenshot of describe pod:

[image]

Here my "helm version" command output is like follows:

```
docker@mildevdcr01:~$ helm version
Client: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", 
GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
Server: &version.Version{SemVer:"v2.14.3", 
GitCommit:"0e7f3b6637f7af8fcfddb3d2941fcc7cbebb0085", GitTreeState:"clean"}
```

**Because of this reason, I tried to addthis command in deployment.yaml**, under metadata.namespace like following,

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ include "spacestudychart.fullname" . }}
  namespace: test
```

I created test and prod, 2 namespaces. But here also it's not working. When I adding like this, I am not getting my service up. I am not able to accessible. And in Jenkins console there is no error. When I defined in helm install --upgrade command it was deploying with default namespace. But here not deploying also.

After this, I removed the namespace from deployment.yaml and added metadata.namespace like the same. There also I am not able to access deployed service. But Jenkins console output still showing success.

Why namespace is not working with my Helm deployment? What changes I need to do here for deploying test/prod instead of this default namespace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove `namespace: test` from all of your chart files and `helm install --namespace=namespace2 ...` should work.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Still I am getting the deployed service in default namespace. I updated my question with tried command. Can you please ook on that ?

Comment: `helm install kubedeploy --namespace=test pipeline/spacestudychart -n kubedeploy` 
`helm install kubedeploy --namespace=test2 pipeline/spacestudychart -n kubedeploy2` 
Should work

Comment: I am getting the error "+ helm install kubedeploy --namespace=test pipeline/spacestudychart -n kubedeploy
Error: This command needs 1 argument: chart name"   . When I ran the command - "helm install kubedeploy --namespace=test pipeline/spacestudychart -n kubedeploy"

Comment: Sorry, should be `helm install pipeline/spacestudychart --namespace=test  -n kubedeploy` and `helm install pipeline/spacestudychart --namespace=test1  -n kubedeploy1`

Comment: Ok..Let me try.

Comment: Here If I need to deploy second time , the same command showing deployment already exist. And I tried to use "helm upgrade --install....." , then also I am getting "Error: unknown shorthand flag: 'n' in -n" error. I tried the command - "helm upgrade --install pipeline/spacestudychart --namespace=test -n kubedeploynewv1". If I am not using --upgrade , then showing the message deployment already exist.So for upgrading my deployment , what changes I need to make here ?

Answer (score 1):

On Helm 3.2+, I would suggest (based on [this thread](https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/6794)) to move the namespace creation to the CLI:

1 ) Add the `--create-namespace` after the `-n` flag:

```
helm upgrade --install <name> <repo> -n <namespace> --create-namespace
```

2 ) Inside the different resources - pass the *Release* namespace:

```
namespace: {{ .Release.Namespace }}
```